# Programmatically set p-tableCheckbox

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have a nested *turbotable* (p-table inside p-table) with checkboxes and expandable rows.

I would like to be able programmatically set certain checkboxes on, e.g. if a user selects a row in the nested table then the ckeckbox of the parent row should get selected also.

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-qaspj4?file=app%2Fexp-table%2Fexp-table.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made quite a lot of changes in the code you joined but main part is here with comments :

```
updateParentSelection(i, parentRow) {
    if (this.cars[i].length > 0) { // if subselection not empty
      if (this.parentSelection.indexOf(parentRow) === -1) { // if parent row not already selected
        this.parentSelection = this.parentSelection.concat(parentRow); // add parent row to parent selection
      }
    } else { // if subselection empty
      this.parentSelection.splice(this.parentSelection.indexOf(parentRow), 1).slice(0); // remove parent row from parent selection
      this.parentSelection = [].concat(this.parentSelection.splice(this.parentSelection.indexOf(parentRow), 1).slice(0)); // trick to update the view
    }
  }
```

Don't hesitate if you have any questions.

See forked [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-gmjujn)

Comment: This works great. One question: who is calling this function `updateParentSelection`?

Comment: Never mind. I see it. It's called on click of child checkbox. Thanks  a lot!